# Unable to query two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can dispaly all of the tutorial_post and the username of the user who posted the post... i wanna see how the sql statement would look like

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any effort? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Try doing some research on how to peform basic MySQL queries.  I.e. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html or https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysql+query+beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make something like this:

```
$postID = 1;//Post id we want to get from the database
$getPost = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id='$postID'");//Get the post by the id
$post = $getPost->fetch_assoc();//Fetch the result to an array
$getUser = $connection->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id=".$post['id']);//Get the username by using the id we got from the $post['user_id']
$user = $getUser->fetch_assoc();//Fetch the second result to an array

//Print everything
echo "Title:".$post['title']."<br/>";
echo "Username:".$user['username']."<br/>";
echo "Body:".$post['body'];
```

I can't really see the names of the tables, so i have just guessed them.

Comment: This is chock full of SQL injection possibilities.

Comment: I know that, but as i can see here he is a beginner and i didn't wanna make it too hard for him, ofcourse you're able to use `real_escape_string` and put the variables inside curly brackets.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to start off beginners with insecure code. @yvensup you should read [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) before you start writing your code. Not only will it teach you to write secure queries from the get-go, it will also give you a good starting point for how to write queries in general.